# Laravel: How do I run a console command inside a migration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, command, migration

I created a Laravel console command in `routes/console.php`. I would like to run this command from a migration? How can I do it?

I would like to avoid using the PHP's `exec()` function because it's unpredictable where the path of my laravel app is going to be and which OS will be run on.

I am using Laravel 5.x

Comment: you need run artisan command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use

```
Artisan::call('email:send');
```

From docs with command parameters

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
    'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands